# Integrating stripe credit card subscription in my laravel app but $request is not containing paymentmethod

Tags: javascript, laravel, stripe-payments

I am trying around since two days now to implement stripe credit card payment with subscription in to my laravel app. I worked through the laravel documentation but I am not able to get the "paymentMethod" in to my $request variable. So what the problem really is the html I am adding through my js is not getting submitted. To make you better understand my problem I am going to post my code.

HTML

```js
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

 const stripe = Stripe('{{ env("STRIPE_KEY") }}');
const elements = stripe.elements();
const cardElement = elements.create('card');
cardElement.mount('#card-element');
const cardHolderName = document.getElementById('name');
const cardButton = document.getElementById('card-button');
const clientSecret = cardButton.dataset.secret;
const cardError = document.getElementById('card-errors');

cardElement.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  if (event.error) {
      cardError.textContent = event.error.message;
  } else {
      cardError.textContent = '';
  }
});
  var form = document.getElementById('subscription-form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const { setupIntent, error } = await stripe.handleCardSetup(
      clientSecret, cardElement, {
          payment_method_data: {
              billing_details: { name: cardHolderName.value }
          }
      }
  );



  if (error) {
      // Display "error.message" to the user...
      console.log(error.message);
  } else {
      // The card has been verified successfully...
      var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
      hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
      hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'payment_method');
      hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', setupIntent.payment_method);
      form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
      // Submit the form
      form.submit();
  }
  });
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    @include('partials.settings-nav')
    <div class="col-lg-9 mt-1 mb-4">
      <form id="payment-form" action="{{ url('settings/card') }}" method="post" >
        @csrf

        <input id="card-holder-name" class="form-control" type="text">

        <!-- Stripe Elements Placeholder -->
        <div id="card-element" class="creditcard"></div>

        <button type="submit" id="card-button" data-secret="{{ $intent->client_secret }}">
            Kreditkarte hinzufügen
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My Controller

```
$paymentMethod = $request->paymentMethod;

auth()->user()->newSubscription('default', 'small')->create($paymentMethod);

return back();
```

I hope someone could help me out here.

Best

Comment: I would recommend adding detailed logs both client-side and server-side to track down exactly what you are receiving client-side, whether `result.setupIntent.payment_method` is set for example, looking at the raw request in Chrome Developer Tools to see if the pm_123 is sent and whether you get it server-side in PHP

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How do you mean that? I always dd my $request to see whats in it but there is only one attribute and thats the csrf token from laravel. In my console there are no errors shown so everything should be ok. Maybe I did not understand you correctly and you mean something different?

Comment: A possibility is the hidden input with the paymentMethod gets not added to the form and so it is not sent to the controller?

Comment: It could be. There are multiple places to debug this that I mentioned and I recommend looking at each one. Log the JS, log what you put in the form, look at the raw HTML in Chrome Developer Tools to confirm the form gets the field and that the form is properly submitted

Comment: Yes it really looks like it. When I am looking in my Chrome dev Tools only the token is in there but I have no idea why that is. When I console.log in my js some of my code gets not triggered. This code here `cardButton.addEventListener('click', ..... gets not triggered, but what I can see everything is setup properly. Sorry for my bad english Edit: jquery is also in place and loaded so the click event should fire?

Comment: What I figured out till now is, if I hardcode the input field into my html with the paymentMethod everything works. I am also able to update then the form again and again and the tables are updated as well.... Edited my js code a little bit but the problem persists the input of the js code gets not injected into my HTML. Also logged my js code but I dont get something out of it. It all looks like stripe does not respond respectively the eventListener gets not triggered? Please if someone could help I really would appreciate that ! :)

Comment: At that point this is a bit too confusing to help on SO. I think you should reach out to Stripe's support team directly https://support.stripe.com/contact

Comment: Solved! The problem was a conflict with vue. I need to implement it with vue now. Thanks for your help anyway